# React Native Login Navigation Issue

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

In my react native app after giving all email and password and pressing login it is not navigating to the homescreen. Can anyone help? [Link of the project](https://snack.expo.dev/@subhrajyoti_mahato/upi-payment)

Please help to navigate

Comment: Something with your Firebase auth. If I remove that code and simply navigate *onClick* I go to the next page

Comment: Can you confirm this `Ensure the "Email/Password" sign-in provider is enabled on the Firebase Console.` As mentioned above if the issue is with Firebase Auth then you can put a console log and check if it is getting success or failure. [Refer](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#emailpassword-sign-in)